# Van der Waals constant $b$ (real gas) chemical form. only

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, physical-constants, interactions

[image: van der waals constants for real gases]

http://www2.ucdsb.on.ca/tiss/stretton/database/van_der_waals_constants.html

I don't understand how to calculate exact constant - b, given only the chemical formula and nothing else.

**Q: T || F --- the following molecules are arranged from largest to smallest b van der Waals constant per mol**

**C2F4, C2H6O, Cl2, Ne**

I know that the Van der Waals eq. is a better description of the behavior of real gases and that it is 
$$ [P + a (n/V)^2] (V/n - b) = RT $$

and that b represents the correction term for the size of the atoms/molecules [=] "units of " volume/mol

I just don't understand how to calculate exact b, given only the chemical formula and nothing else.

After looking at the website could reason a bit through electronegativity that C2F4, must be the largest --- am I supposed to plug in fixed values for P, V and T.

like give P, V, and T any values? for all calculations?

Comment: The van der Waals constants $a$ and $b$ are empirically determined. How would you go about calculating them?

Comment: I don't think there is a simple relationship between chemical formula and van der Waal's $b$. For example I would expect organic componds which are isomers of each other to have different values for $b$ dispite having the same chemical formula. However the values for $b$ for all the componds in your question are given in the site you linked to.

Comment: This is a problem for class and it says to show work. - so I think there's supposed to be a relationship?

Answer (score 1):

Emailed my TAs and they said this: ( for anyone who comes across this later)

> Ranking them by size is the right idea.  To mathematically estimate the size of each molecule you may assume each element has a spherical volume, and that the volume of the molecule is the sum of it elements.  Google is your friend for known values about the elements *[ie. look up the atomic radius and use the normal volume formula].*

**Additionally another Physics_Stack Exchange question covers a related concept (linked)

[Van der Waals equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/238089/van-der-waals-equation)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** calculate the Van der Waals constants. They are determined through experiments. The question doesn't ask you to, it only asks you to **compare** the Van der Waals constants, which is something that we definitely can do.

Remember that the constant **a** encodes the attraction between the gas molecules while **b** encodes both the size of the molecules and the repulsion between the gas molecules. You can use this information to attempt to solve the question, but $C_2H_6O$ is problematic here as it has two isomers, an ether and an alcohol, and the constants will be different for both.

Comment: I can see how the question is a non - valuable one? The TAs who made the hw wanted kids to calculate the constants somehow? I don't remember the original hw.

Comment: If it does ask you to calculate the values, I don't know how, you would probably need more information such as the VW radius which would make the calculations trivial. This is the limit of my high school knowledge ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: This was for a college level thermomdynamics course for engineers.